# how to show zero on the left before decimal point when using round()?

Tags: sql, oracle

I used `round()` function to show the file size in from byte to MB.

The data was like the following-

```
file_size
----------
2463
```

I used this to convert-

```
round(document.file_size / (1024*1024), 3) file_size
```

Now the data is showing like this-

```
file_size
----------
.002
```

But, what I want is like this-

```
file_size
----------
0.002
```

Just the left most zero. How can I have this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `TO_CHAR(round(document.file_size / (1024*1024), 3), 990.000) file_size`

More information you can find here: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::NO::P11_QUESTION_ID:2739503983093

Answer (score 1):

you want a leading zero... try this:

```
to_char(round(document.file_size / (1024*1024), 3),0999) file_size
```

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm

Answer (score 1):

Use `0` element to return leading zero output. [Read more..](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#i34510)

```
select to_char(round(2463 / (1024*1024), 3),'0.999') from dual
```

**[SQLFiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7/3803)**

Answer (score 0):

It would be correct to use this :

```
     SELECT TO_CHAR(round(2463 / (1024*1024), 3),'90.999') FROM DUAL
```

I completely disagree with the above solutions.